# MobX action transfer to function as callback

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Question:

if I have store (pseudo code)

```
export default class MainStore {
  @observable someObservable = [];

  someFuncWithApi(actionFuncFromComponent) {
    apiCall.then(res => actionFuncFromComponent(res.loadPercentage)).then(() => ....)
  }
}

const mainStore = new MainStore;

....

@inject('mainStore')
@observer
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
  @observable percentage = null;

  @action
  setPercentage(percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage
  }

  someHandle() {
    this.props.mainStore.someFuncWithApi(this.setPercentage)
  }
}
```

This need for changing load percentage, someFuncWithApi is called but not change percentage or rerender in component. Please, tell me the right way for this.

Answer (score 4):

`this.props.mainStore.someFuncWithApi(this.setPercentage)`

calls an unbound `this.setPercentage`. Either pass `(x) => this.setPercentage(x)` or bind the function to `this`

Comment: Silly mistake, thanks for the answer, of course this works